# Username & Password for selling page Yes or No?

Tags: usability, navigation, hyperlinks, password, username

I appreciate your given opinion about this:

I intend to send an email to a specific target audience in order to offer small business owners (around the world) a product which is not cheap. (I don't give specific details because I want an opinion about the idea in general)

My plan is to send business owners to a dedicated page where they get more details, download a business marketing guide for their type of busines, and ask for their contact details so that they can be contacted for more details and maybe make a purchase.

Should I simply give them the link to the web page?

OR...
Restrict the page entry telling the business owners that they get access with  their unique username and password, and

Give each one a username which is similar to the business name, and a password like SUCCESS, or WEALTH101 or PLENTY4U.  In other words a password with a positive feeling.

What do you think?

Thanks,
Erez

Comment: It sounds like you want to send out spam that the recipients have to go through a log-in process to view. Spam AND forms in one? Make sure you add in a CAPTCHA too just to annoy them further.

Comment: tempted to add this as a full answer to the question but I don't think such answers are too appreciated. I'll just post as a comment. My answer is: No

Comment: Since you are asking for my opinion, here it is. Yes, of course ask for a password. To make sure they typed it correctly, maybe even validate it by asking the user to enter it twice? Did you also think of other passwords like 'enlarge' and 'freexxx'? They seem to be very successful at making people feel comfortable at your site. But no, in all fairness: I think you are asking for the best way to send Spam and I don't think this is the place to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself the following:

- Is the content on the web page supposed to be disclosed and hidden from unauthorized users?
- Do you want to restrict social sharing from those users you’re e-mailing?
- Is it a bad thing that users you haven’t e-mailed also get hold of the information through trusted friends?
- Do users in general trust an obviously unsafe password tailored by an unknown person?
- Do users in general get a lot of advertisement e-mail, and do they actually read it?
- Don’t e-mail sent to multiple recipients have the potential to get SPAM-marked by clever e-mail clients and servers?

If you answered **yes** to all of these questions, then go ahead and try your business plan!